# When posting a FB adgroup I get error campaign 1487006

Tags: facebook-graph-api

It says "You must specify a campaign, and the campaign specified must belong to the account specified and must not be deleted."

Even though I'm pretty sure the campaign was created, not deleted and belongs to this ad account.

See attached screenshots.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/85o82n2e2z6091z/Screenshot%202014-08-01%2018.38.56.png
https://www.dropbox.com/s/s9qg48ud90b3tnb/Screenshot%202014-08-01%2018.08.24.png

And here is the code

//create campaign
  graph.post(ad_account_id+'/adcampaign_groups', campaign_data, function(err, cdata){

```
var campaign_id = cdata['id'];
console.log(campaign_id);
console.log(cdata);

//create the creative first
graph.post(ad_account_id+'/adcreatives', creative_data, function(err, data){
  //save to content
  //res.jsonp(data);
  content.facebook_ad_creative_id = data['id'];
  content.save(function(err, content){


        console.log(campaign_id);

        //create an ad.
        var options = {
          'name' : 'promoting post '+content.content,
          'bid_type' : 'CPM',
          'campaign_id' : campaign_id,
          'max_bid' : req.query['max_bid'],
          'creative' : { 'creative_id' : content.facebook_ad_creative_id },
          'targeting' : FacebookHelper.extract_targeting_spec_from_url(req)
        }
        console.log(options);
        console.log(ad_account_id);
        graph.post( ad_account_id+'/adgroups', options, function(err, data) {
            res.jsonp(data);
        });
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue with the naming of FB's Ads API, `campaign_id` here actually means `adset_id`.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adgroup#create